# The Witcher 3: Who ate the living as well?

Tags: video-games, the-witcher

> Vesemir: Wait -- hear that?
>
> Geralt: I hear it, I smell it. Ghouls.
>
> [They slay the hellish intruders.]
>
> Vesemir: Of course, when armies pass, necrophages follow. Let's go before any more show up.
>
> Geralt: I ever tell you about this sorcerer I knew? Couldn't stop talking about how useful they are as creatures.
>
> Vesemir: Because you can brew potions from their blood?
>
> Geralt: Heh, no. Because by eating rotting corpses, they prevent epidemics.
>
> Vesemir: Hrmph. **Did he know they eat the living as well?**
>
> Geralt: No. Really upset him, too... His theory collapsed.

The sorcerers ate the rotting necrophages corpses who also ate the living?

Comment: Can you quote some of the dialogue shortly before these lines? I suspect the answer to your question may lie therein.

Comment: You really might want to ask some questions on [ell.se] since this kind of question seems founded on a lack of understanding of how antecedents to pronouns are determined.  You have a plural pronoun "they."  What is the previous plural noun in context?  "necrophages"  That's what "they" refers to.  It's a pretty basic rule of English.

Comment: The sorcerer ate the rotting necrophages corpses who ate the living?

Comment: The troll ate them. Do not feed the troll.

Answer (score 4):

The "they" in this conversation refers to the necrophages - the creatures that are drawn to the corpses of those fallen in battle.

The sorcerer that Geralt mentioned claims that *they* (the necrophages) serve a purpose. Vesemir asks if it's because *their* (the necrophages') blood can be used for potions. Geralt replies that it's because *they* (the necrophages) eat the corpses that would otherwise spread disease. Vesemir points out that *they* (the necrophages) attack and eat the living as well.

Whenever the sorcerer is mentioned by pronoun, it is as he/him.

Comment: Note that the "necrophages" (lit. "eaters of dead") are the ghouls mentioned at the start.

Comment: How eat the living would spread epidemics?

Comment: Eating the living won't spread an epidemic - the sorcerer was saying that eating the dead would prevent epidemics (dead bodies that are rotting produce a lot of nasty diseases, that's why we preserve/bury/cremate them). However, ghouls eating living people quickly results in a lot fewer living people.

Comment: @HorusKol - And decrease the surplus population...

Comment: So how how the decrease of  the living  population would spread decease?